# Add text to textbox when check if radio box is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a little project for myself in order to better understand javascript. Not looking to be an expert just have a better understanding.

I am making a dilution calculator and I am wondering what the best way to insert the units (either oz or mL) into the input boxes and output divs based on whether or not a radio is selected. I would like this to automatically happen on the page load as well as on change of the radio.

```
<div class="input-group input-margin-top">
  <input type="text" id="containersize" class="form-control" value="0" onclick="this.select();">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="ounces" checked> oz
  </span>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="millilitres"> mL
  </span>     
</div>
```

Here is how I have the HTML setup for the radio buttons

I am also wondering what the best way to not have NaN show up when you select the mL radio before entering any values. I was thinking an if statement to check if the value of the first box was zero than do not run the convert function. I am open to ideas here.

Here is what I currently have, keep in mind that about 48 hours ago I had never worked with Javascript [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dhyue0p/)

I am all for learning how to do this so if you have any good links on the subject let me know.

Thanks so much for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it in action here:  https://jsfiddle.net/7dhyue0p/1/

I've added comments throughout the code so you can see what's happening every step of the way.  If there's anything that you are confused or unsure about, don't hesitate to ask, I'm happy to help.

**Note:  I highly recommend learning at least the basics of JavaScript before working with any libraries (like jQuery)**

```
function calculate(event) {

    // Get the container size
    var containerSize = parseFloat(document.getElementById("containersize").value);

    // Get the dilution
    var dilution = parseFloat(document.getElementById("dilution").value);

    // Calculate the concentrate result
    var concentrateResult = containerSize / ((dilution) + (1));

    // Calculate the water result
    var waterResult = concentrateResult * dilution;

    // Get an array of all of the radio elements in "inlineRadioOptions"
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("inlineRadioOptions");

    // Declare the variable "unit" to hold the name of the unit
    var unit;

    // Loop through the radio buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {

        // If this radio button is checked
        if (radios[i].checked) {

            // Assign the value of the radio button to the variable "unit"
            unit = radios[i].value;
        }
    }

    // Find the value of the element that was clicked - if the value is "oz"...
    if (event.target.value === "oz") {
        // Update your elements
        document.getElementById("containersize").value = (containerSize / (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
        document.getElementById("concentrateresults").innerHTML = (concentrateResult / (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
        document.getElementById("waterresults").innerHTML = (waterResult / (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
    } else if (event.target.value === "ml") {  // Repeat for "ml"
        document.getElementById("containersize").value = (containerSize * (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
        document.getElementById("concentrateresults").innerHTML = (concentrateResult * (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
        document.getElementById("waterresults").innerHTML = (waterResult * (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
    } else {  // Otherwise, if this function wasn't triggered by changing the radio button...
        document.getElementById("containersize").value = containerSize.toFixed(1) + unit;
        document.getElementById("concentrateresults").innerHTML = concentrateResult.toFixed(1) + unit;
        document.getElementById("waterresults").innerHTML = waterResult.toFixed(1) + unit;
    }
};

// Event Listener to make everything automatic
// Get an array of every input
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

// Loop through the inputs
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

    // Add an event handler for each input
    inputs[i].addEventListener("change", function (event) {
        // Capture the event and pass it into the calculate() function
        calculate(event);
    });
}
```

I changed a lot of the code that you had in there.

I combined everything into the `calculate()` function to make it repeatable.

First - when coding in JavaScript - name your variables so you understand what they are.  Using arbitrary letters as variables is not a good idea.  You should be able to read the code and understand what's going on.

Second - I added an event listener on all of the inputs on the page, and capture the event to pass into the `calculate()` function.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("change", function (event) {
        calculate(event);
    });
}
```

The reason for passing in the event listener is so we can determine within that one function which element is clicked (for changing between oz and ml)

```
if (event.target.value === "oz") {
    document.getElementById("containersize").value = (containerSize / (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
    document.getElementById("concentrateresults").innerHTML = (concentrateResult / (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
    document.getElementById("waterresults").innerHTML = (waterResult / (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
} else if (event.target.value === "ml") {
    document.getElementById("containersize").value = (containerSize * (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
    document.getElementById("concentrateresults").innerHTML = (concentrateResult * (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
    document.getElementById("waterresults").innerHTML = (waterResult * (29.5735)).toFixed(1) + unit;
} else {
    document.getElementById("containersize").value = containerSize.toFixed(1) + unit;
    document.getElementById("concentrateresults").innerHTML = concentrateResult.toFixed(1) + unit;
    document.getElementById("waterresults").innerHTML = waterResult.toFixed(1) + unit;
}
```

This function also eliminates your NaN error and it also adds either "oz" or "ml" as requested.

---

**EDITED per Comments**

You can add multiple event listeners to the same element, even if it calls the same function like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        calculate(event);
    });
    inputs[i].addEventListener("change", function (event) {
        calculate(event);
    });
}
```

Here, I added the "keyup" event so it will re-calculate as the number is changed in the text boxes.  I kept the "change" event handler so it will work as expected on the radio buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, looking at what you came up with really showed me how convoluted I was trying making it. My variable naming was terrible and I will have to improve on that. The comments actually make this pretty straightforward. 

My next question is if there is a good way with change event listeners to avoid having to hit enter or click on blank space to get it to fire? I realize that setting it to keyup would cripple the radio boxes.

Would it be a case of breaking up the eventlisteners? One for keyup on the text inputs and one for radios?

Comment: No problem at all :-).  As far as the events, you can assign the same function to a keyup event and a change event to cover all of your inputs.  I'll add this to my example later to show you how it's done.  Also, don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if it works for you.  Thanks!

Comment: @Shane -- I've edited my answer to include the additional event handler.  Let me know if there's anything else you need help with :-).  Don't forget to vote and accept this as an answer if it works for you.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much Howard. I apologize but it seems like I cannot vote the answer up but I did accept it. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, more like ideological propagandizing -

But, since you asked for advice, I will impose my views.

Many on here will advise against tackling jQuery before learning javascript proper, but I disagree. I began with jQuery and was productive within hours, and I am now filling-in what I missed about javascript after having designed numerous sites.

Here is an example of why you might prefer to learn jQuery over plain javascript:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qntrh06x/)</kbd>

**The jQuery way:**

```
// Event Listener to make everything automatic
$('#containersize, #dilution').keyup(function(){
    a = parseFloat($("#containersize").val() );
    b = parseFloat($("#dilution").val() );
    c = a / ((b) + (1));
    d = c * b;
    $("#concentrateresults").html( c.toFixed(1) );
    $("#waterresults").html( d.toFixed(1) );
});

// Event Listener to change the units
$('#ounces, #millilitres').click(function(){
    btn = this.id;
    a = parseFloat($("#containersize").val());
    b = parseFloat($("#concentrateresults").html() );
    c = parseFloat($("#waterresults").html() );
    if (btn=='ounces'){
        d = a / (29.5735)
        e = b / (29.5735)
        f = c / (29.5735)
    }else{
        d = a * (29.5735)
        e = b * (29.5735)
        f = c * (29.5735)
    }
    $("#containersize").val(d.toFixed(1) );
    $("#concentrateresults").html( e.toFixed(1) );
    $("#waterresults").html( f.toFixed(1) );
});
```

Much less typing -- especially over an entire project -- using the jQuery way. Also, jQuery takes care of all cross-browser issues for you. With javascript you must code for each browser yourself. For most developers, jQuery is faster and easier.

---

NOTE: Before you can use jQuery commands, you must include the jQuery library on your page -- usually between the HEAD tags, like this:

```
<head>
    <!-- other stuff in head -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

*If you use a CDN to load jQuery, as in the above example, it is probably already be pre-loaded from other websites.*

---

---

If you want some fast lessons on jQuery, find free 10-min video tuts here:

[TheNewBoston.com](https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=32)

or at

[phpAcademy.org](https://phpacademy.org/videos/jquery-basics)

Comment: While searching the web for solutions to my issues I saw so much jQuery that looked like it would solve a ton of my issues. I will check out those links and see what I can learn. Thanks so much.

Comment: If this is the best solution to your question, please remember to accept it (click the checkmark) as the favored answer. Doing so will also close the question, so that others don't spend time on it. Thanks, and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

> I am also wondering what the best way to not have NaN show up when you
>   select the mL radio before entering any values.

You can simply avoid NaN by using several tricks, one of them is using `||`:

```
parseFloat(""); //         <-- NaN
parseFloat("") || 0; //    <-- 0
parseFloat("foo") || 0; // <-- 0
```

Skipping parse  methods:

```
+("") || 0; //             <-- 0
+("3") || 0; //            <-- 3
+(".003") || 0; //         <-- 0.003
```

Answer (score -1):

in your function calc, if you make a condition like this :
`if(a>0){
    c = a/((b) + (1));
    d = c*b;
    }`

the NAN will dissapear.

for the page load, you can use the `<body onload=" myFunction()">` to execute a function you need.

Comment: This only answers part of the question